# SQL group on condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of data in PL/SQL that would look like this:

```
A 1
A 0
A 0
B 0
B 0
B 0
C 1
C 0
D 0
```

For each unique letter i need to group the numbers so that IF ATLEAST one 1 exists for that letter, return only that record with 1, and if no 1 exists for that letter, return ALL 0s.

So the return would be:

```
A 1
B 0
B 0
B 0
C 1
D 0
```

Is it possible to somehow group like this in a select statement?

Comment: Why are there multiple rows in the resultset for "B"?

Comment: If there are 2 `(E, 1)` rows, how many of them do you want in the result?

Comment: @GMB because it does not have a 1, all values for B need to be returned

Comment: @jarlh in my case it is only possible to have one 1 for each letter, but however many 0 (i mean the initial data would never have multiple 1s for unique letter)

Comment: @forpas i was not aware which answer was first / second, so i selected the top one, if i could i'd mark both answers but it seems i cant. I am also not sure about the rules of selecting the correct answer based on time, but i can mark yours.

Comment: @forpas Also thank you very much for the answer, it did exactly what i wanted ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where t.col2 = 1
or not exists (select 1 from tablename where col1 = t.col1 and col2 = 1)
```

Replace `col1` and `col2` with the actual column names.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=67dee683052985ce7e555b2ea11055eb).
Results:

```
> COL1 | COL2
> :--- | ---:
> A    |    1
> B    |    0
> B    |    0
> B    |    0
> C    |    1
> D    |    0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can require that either the row has value 1 or that no other rows exist for the given letter with the value 1:

```
select letter_col, num_col
  from mytable t1
 where num_col = 1 or
       not exists (select * 
                     from mytable
                     where letter_col = t1.letter_col and
                           num_col = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select col, val
from (
    select col, val, 
        max(val) over(partition by col) maxval,
        row_number() over(partition by col order by val desc) rn
    from mytable
) t
where maxval = 0 or rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use window functions, you can do:

```
select col1, col2
from (select t.*, max(col2) over (partition by col1) as max_col2
      from t
     ) t
where col2 = 1 or max_col2 = 0;
```

see the demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=420e9efb1bc19ce8eebae903abada961